# Issues booting the installer - AMD based system

Tags: drivers, kernel, amd-graphics, 17.04, amd-processor

I'm having sirious issues with starting up the Ubuntu installer. I tried several Versions 17.04 x64 / x86, 14.04.05 x64 / x86 and none of the works.

With the flags - xforcevesa nomodeset nolapic - I managed to pass the initialisation phase (Ubuntu 17.04 x64).

Unfortunately, at that stage the Network Manager and Logind suddenly crashes and the kernel stucks in a loop by trying to start them up. After a while (10-15 min from the first failure) the monitor turns balack and keeps flashing in 2 min intervals. It seem that the kernel is trying to start up the xserver but keeps failing.

Could that be an driver issue and if yes, does anyone have suggestions how to get around this?

I would be grateful for any advice or workarounds!

My current system config:

-> AMD FX-6200 Six-Core CPU

-> Gigabyte GA880-GMA-USB3 - latest bios available version F4g (Chipset AMD 880G / South Bridge AMD SB850)

-> AMD Radeon HD 6870 (xfx)

-> 12 GB DDR3 RAM (2 x 4GB + 2 x 2GB)

-> 1 GB Toshiba hard drive (SATA 3)

During the start up I get the following error messages (with the mentioned flags set):

[AMD - Error - no UMS support](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uf6q.jpg)
[Failing Services](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jh2Ye.jpg)

Comment: If nobody comes up with a better idea, you might want to try some alternate installers. I haven't used anything but the mini.iso in several years, but there used to be an option for non-graphical installation with the main live/installer disk. You could also try the mini.iso. It's not hard to use apt to build your system once you get it booting to a command line.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help! I'm just surprised that I'm the only one with an AMD Chipset trying to get Ubuntu to start up and experiencing this issues. I was considering the minimal installer as last resort...

Comment: I tried the minimal installer now and I get the main menue to work - unfortunately with the nolapic flag my mounse and keyboard don't get recognised and without the kernel get stuck after **NET: Registered protocol family 16** message. After a while I get **cpuidle: using govenor ladder** message. Any ideas?

Comment: 'fraid not. Sorry. I'm not very deep re the boot process. Hopefully somebody like Oldfred or Steeldriver will drop in help you. If you make no progress with this for a while, just as an experiment, you might try installing a non-debian derived distro to see if it works. Might learn something from the comparison.  PClos was pretty good last time  I tried it. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

In case somebody struggels as I did - after hours and hours of research I eventually found the solution. Apparently the drivers were all ok. In my case I had just simply to deactive the C1 support within the BIOS options. I'm not fully aware of the consequenses yet, but the result looks promising. Thanks Lew Rockwell Fan for your support!

### Update:

**I was able to trackdown the issue - basically the C1E specific interrupt does not work properly. You can still have the C1E function enabled in your BIOS in order to keep your system running efficiently. The workaround would be to set the nolapic_timer for x86 or the noapictimer flag for x64 based systems during boot.**